# Access data's variable in other variable's function - undefined

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, vue.js, element-ui

I need to make an date validation in Vue depending on Vue models.

The problem is how this date validation works. I need to define variable in `data` segment which contains `disabledDate` function. So here is the simplified code:

Template:

```html
<el-date-picker type="date"
  v-model="date1"
  :picker-options="datePickerOptions1">
</el-date-picker>
```

JS:

```js
data() {
  return {
    date: null,
    rev: {
      validDate: null
    },
    datePickerOptions1: {
      disabledDate(date) {
        return date < this.rev.validDate;
      }
    }
  }
},
mounted: function() {
  var today = new Date();
  this.rev.validDate = today.getDate();
}
```

The console says `this.rev.validDate` is `undefined`.

In my case `this.rev.validDate` is fetched from database while component is mounted and depending on this that `el-date-picker` should work.

I would ask for any suggestions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `disabledDate` is deeply nested to where it loses the current Vue instance (otherwise accessible via `this` context). To work around this, you could assign the instance to a variable, like so:

```
data() {
  const vm = this;

  return {
    date: null,
    rev: {
      validDate: null
    },
    datePickerOptions1: {
      disabledDate(date) {
        return date < vm.rev.validDate;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or with arrow function:

```js
data: vm => ({
  date: null,
  rev: {
    validDate: null
  },
  datePickerOptions1: {
    disabledDate(date) {
      return date < vm.rev.validDate;
    }
  }
})
```